# Jenkins "Batch-Build" fails every time

Tags: windows, batch-file, build, jenkins, errorlevel

here is my configuration.
-> sorry, is german... ( the batch thing is important )

http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=configurationknjkj.jpg

And here is the result (console).

http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=console_outputjpkxi.jpg

I dont know why.

**The Tip of Jenkins is:** If the %ERRORLEVEL% is not equal 0, then the build fails.

What i did?

```
set ERRORLEVEL=0
```

or

```
exit 0
```

or

```
exit /B 0
```

**Why the build fails every time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you set the cobertura plugin, but it cannot find your output file (which fails the build).

Try removing both the JUnit and cobertura reports and try again.

Remember that some of the post build actions can also fail your build.